# django - referring to static files in templates

Tags: django, relative-path, django-staticfiles

I have the templates for my django app designed by a web design app (axure). So all the static files reference in these template files are relative, such as

```
<img src="/resources/image/icon.gif"/>
```

I followed the instruction here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ to modify the settings for the app to include static files and have STATIC_URL fixed. However, by that way, I still have to put this token `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in front of every static files reference.

Is there a generic way to do it that makes django to accept these relative paths to static files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

That's not a "relative" path. It's what's called "relative absolute". When you prepend with `/`. It tells the browser to reference the following path directly from the domain. This has nothing to do with Django. It has to do with the browser, and they *all* work that way.

There's nothing special about `{{ STATIC_URL }}`; it's just an easy and safe way to prefix your references to static files with the right path. You could actually hard-code the full URL in the your HTML:

```
<img src="/path/to/static/resources/image/icon.gif"/>
```

But if your STATIC_URL ever changed, you'd be out of luck. That's why you use `{{ STATIC_URL }}`, so that no matter whether it's set to "/static/" or "http://cdn.someprovider.com/myproject/something-else/static/" your references always work.

Long and short, no, there's no "generic way". You have to tell the browser exactly where it can find the file, and that requires using `{{ STATIC_URL }}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a backend like nginx you could set your /staticimage to point to /path/to/static/resources/image/ and then use /staticimage.

I'm sure any web server you are using can be given such a path mapping.